# Qt- Appending to QList

Tags: c++, qt

I created **QList** from class in global. 

**global.h:**

```
class CLastMessage
{
public:
    QString id;
    QString message;
};
typedef QList<CLastMessage> CLastMessageList;
```

I called it in another header:

**message.h:**

```
CLastMessageList m_lastMessage;
```

but I'm having problem to append new values to this Qlist. in **message.cpp** I want to append new id and messages, but I don't know how to do that in the best way. for example I want to add new id to this list. is it correct?

**message.cpp:**

```
CLastMessageList m_lastMessage;
m_lastMessage.id = "1";
```

Comment: IMO m_lastMessage is a misleading name for a list of messages

Comment: yeah..you're right. I want draft messages, and I must modify that name@Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your custom class is currently assignable, so you don't need an explicit copy constructor or assignment operator.

The problem is how you add an item to the list:

```
CLastMessageList m_lastMessage; // this is declaring a new list
m_lastMessage.id = "1"; // this is invalid, as id is not a property of QList
```

This code re-declares an object of the list (m_lastMessage). You're then trying to set a variable to the list, but id is not a member of the list, but a member of an object which you can store in the list. So, create an object first, then add it to your list:

```
CLastMessage message;
message.id = "1";
m_lastMessage.append(message);
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. How to search on m_lastMessage for specific id?            for (int j=0 ; j<m_lastMessage.size() ; ++j) m_lastMessage.id = "1" ?

Comment: Not quite right. You need to reference an item at an index, so *m_lastMessage[i].id*, or *m_lastMessage.itemAt(i).id*